# Swift - Obtener N caracteres de un string

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

eh estado investigando y necesito a un string que me da una fecha de tipo string, guardar en otro string el mes igualmente de tipo string.

```
finalFlightsDate: String = "29-09-20"
```

y guardar únicamente el mes, y que quede algo así

```
finalFlightsDateMonth: String = "09"
```

¿Como puedo sacar unicamente el mes (MM) del string *finalFlightsDate* y guardarlo en *finalFlightsDateMonth*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar `split` para separar el string de acuerdo al `-`. Entonces quedaría así:

```
var finalFlightsDate: String = "29-09-20"
//Asignas el valor del split a una variable
var finalSeparado = finalFlightsDate.split(separator: "-")
//La variable se convierte en un array con los valores en cada posición.
print(finalSeparado[1]) // Imprime 09
```

Comment: muchas gracias!